# Error en cshtml al conectar a SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio, cshtml

Estoy pasándome de PHP y MySQL a ASP.NET Core y Sql Server.

Tengo un problema al intentar mostrar información con mi página cshtml. El error que me muestra es el siguiente.

[image: Error mostrado en pantalla]

El código que estoy usando es similar a como conectaba y mostraba información con PHP y MySQL, pero aun no estoy tan familiarizado con C# en diseńo web, uso el siguiente código:

[image: Código de C#]

Finalmente les dejo mi consulta en SQL Server, espero su respuesta, saludos!

[image: consulta con SQL server]

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede suceder porque no estas aplicando la inyección de dependencias correspondiente para obtener el proveedor utilizado para enlazar la base de datos a tu pagina en razor. mira tu archivo .cs y ubica en el OnGetAsync() si efectivamente estas obteniendo el contexto de la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar la libreria `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` que al parecer no la tienes en tu proyecto. Abre la [consola de nuget](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell) y ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version 4.7.0
```